# Setting proper alignment of packed long long on GCC to use use with avx2 instructions

Tags: c, language-lawyer, x86-64, memory-alignment, avx2

***Introduction:***

I'm writing a function to process 4 packed `long long int` in `x86_64` assembly using `AVX2` instruction. Here is how my header file looks like:

`avx2.h`

```
#define AVX2_ALIGNMENT 32

// Processes 4 packed long long int and 
// returns a pointer to a result 
long long * process(long long *);
```

The assembly implementation of the `process` function looks as follows:

`avx2.S`:

```
global process

process:
    vmovaps ymm0, [rdi]
    ;other instructions omitted
```

The `vmovaps ymm0, [rdi]` requires `rdi` to be 32-bytes aligned. In assembly it is controlled by the `align 32` directive.

***The problem***:

When compiling with `GCC` it has the [`__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) definition which on my implementation is 16. The C18 Standard at `6.2.8/3` claims that

> An extended alignment is represented by an alignment greater than
>   `_Alignof (max_align_t)`. It is implementation-defined whether any extended alignments are supported and the storage durations for which
>   they are supported.

So the implementation-defined extended alignment on GCC is also 16 and I'm not sure if the code causes UB:

```
#include "avx2.h"

//AVX2_ALIGNMENT = 32, __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__ = 16
_Alignas(AVX2_ALIGNMENT) long long longs[] = {1, 32, 432, 433};
long long *result = process(longs);
```

Is there a way to rewrite the code without UB? (I'm aware about intrinsic `immintrin.h`, this is not the topic of the question).

Comment: You could of course just use `vmovups` instead of `vmovaps` and forget about alignment.

Comment: @PaulR I just checked the latency/TP/uops for the [`vmovaps`](https://uops.info/html-instr/VMOVAPS_M256_YMM.html)/[`vmovups`](https://uops.info/html-lat/SKL/VMOVUPS_M256_YMM-Measurements.html) and noticed that they are almost the same (both have 10c latency and 2uops) on `Skylake` so propabably `vmovups` should be prefferable... No?

Comment: if your data happens to be 32 byte aligned then there should be no noticeable difference in performance. If it's not aligned then you may see a relatively small difference in performance due to fairly subtle cache/memory issues, which may or not be significant in your use case, depending on just how performance-critical the code is, you memory access pattern, and how much computation you're doing after the initial load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your code is already free of UB**.  Any decent compiler would error on an `_Alignas()` that it didn't support.

Note that the standard says presence/absence of this support is *implementation-defined*.  It doesn't mention UB anywhere.  **An implementation should know what it supports and check at compile time whether it can support a given `_Alignas` or not.**

A bad low-quality implementation could I *guess* decide that too-high values for `_Alignas()` were UB.  I haven't actually checked.

---

The implementations that can compile this code (gcc/clang/MSVC/ICC) all support at least `_Alignas(256)` for automatic and static storage, AFAIK.  (I left out SunCC which may still be around and may have AVX2 support.  I assume it's fine too but I haven't looked at its asm output) 
 Probably nearly arbitrarily large, especially for static storage.

All of those compilers definitely do know how to over-align the stack to 32 or 64, so there's no reason they can't do it to arbitrarily large except for stack-size limits.

**It should be safe to assume that every compiler that supports Intel intrinsics also supports extended alignments for `_Alignas()` at least up to the size of a couple cache lines.**

(FYI, you can `#include <alignof.h>` so you can use `alignas()` the same as you would in C++).

---

#### Caveat: MinGW stack alignment for `__m256` variables

Last I heard, MinGW is still broken.  It knows how to align the stack for `_Alignas(32)`, but fails to do so for `__m256`/`__m256i/d` variables, potentially spilling/reloading them with misaligned `vmovaps`.

Or something like this.  If you care about MinGW, better look into this.  Or just use clang when targeting Windows.

Comment: __An implementation should know what it supports and check at compile time whether it can support a given _Alignas or not.__ I tested it with my `gcc-7.4.0` and the maximum allowed alignment which worked fine was `8192 * 8192 * 4`. Trying to set `_Alignas(8192 * 8192 * 8)` causes `error: requested alignment is too large`.

Comment: @St.Antario: oh good, thanks for testing that at least gcc works the way I expected.